# Flutter google map not rendering when changing camera position

Tags: google-maps, flutter, gps

I am trying to show a `Stack` widget containing a `Google Map` on the bottom and an icon (car) on top, in a way that the car should be following the path on the road given by different GPS coordinate positions (lat, lon).

To simulate that, the car icon is always drawn in the center of the Stack and the Google Map is moved under the icon using:

```
_mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(
          newPosition.target.latitude,
          newPosition.target.longitude,
        ),
        zoom: 19,
      ),
    ));
```

here is the drawing of the map + the icon:

```
Widget drawStack() {
    return Container(
        width: 930,
        height: 524,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildGoogleMaps(),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/carIconMap.png", width: 50, height: 93),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Everything works fine at the beginning but as more coordinate points are given, there is a moment (part outside of the Container), when the map seems to not be loaded when the camera is moving.

I have tried to give the map the maximum and minimum lat,lon bounds via the property `cameraTargetBounds` of the GoogleMap constructor.

But nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

this worked to me

```
 CameraPosition _initialPosition = CameraPosition(target: _latlng, zoom: 16);
 Position currentLocation;



_getLocation() async {
   currentLocation = await Geolocator()
       .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

   var newPosition = CameraPosition(
       target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
       zoom: 16);

   CameraUpdate update =CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(newPosition);
   CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdate.zoomTo(16);

   _mapController.moveCamera(update);      
 }
```

and this is my widget

```
GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,

            ),
```